# Cant download Liferay past release

Tags: download, liferay-6, release

I have been trying to download a past Liferay release of the EE version.

Liferay Portal 6.2 EE SP11

https://www.liferay.com/community/releases/-/asset_publisher/nSr2/content/id/52182830

However when i click on download it redirects me to the SP12 download link.

Is there no other way to download a legacy version.

Comment: I think that is something you should ask your support contact at Liferay...

Comment: Here there are all realeases: http://www.liferay.com/it/community/releases

Comment: @TobiasLiefke thanks i obtained the version via my support.

Answer (score 0):

As an EE customer you should have access to the customer portal at liferay.com.
This is the place where you'll be able to download all the previous versions of LIferay EE.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't now that customer portal only bring it up 7.0 onwards... Does anyone knows if there is any "hidden" place to download 6.2 ee from?